# file_put_contents multipart file upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I have php multipart file upload max chunk size is 5MB.

```
$part = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
if(file_put_contents(tmp_path.$_REQUEST['hash'].'.'.pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $part, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX)){
 echo 'ok';
} else {
 echo 'error';
}
```

With slower internet connection everything works just fine, but if upload is from faster internet connection at 3-4 part it's getting error.

Is there a better way to move part of uploading file from php tmp to my folder and append that part to file.?

Comment: What error? And how does your chunked upload work? Did you in any way ensure that the parts are send in the right order?